# Execute command block in primitive in NetLogo extension

Tags: api, scala, netlogo

I'm writing a primitive that takes in two agentsets and a command block. It needs to call a few functions, execute the command block in the current context, and then call another function. Here's what I have so far:

```
class WithContext(pushGraphContext: GraphContext => Unit, popGraphContext: api.World => GraphContext)
  extends api.DefaultCommand {
  override def getSyntax = commandSyntax(
    Array(AgentsetType, AgentsetType, CommandBlockType))

  def perform(args: Array[Argument], context: Context) {
    val turtleSet = args(0).getAgentSet.requireTurtleSet
    val linkSet = args(1).getAgentSet.requireLinkSet
    val world = linkSet.world
    val gc = new GraphContext(world, turtleSet, linkSet)
    val extContext = context.asInstanceOf[ExtensionContext]
    val nvmContext = extContext.nvmContext
    pushGraphContext(gc)
    // execute command block here
    popGraphContext(world)
  }
}
```

I looked at some examples that used `nvmContext.runExclusively`, but that looked like it's specifically for having a given agentset run the command block. I want the current agent (possibly the observer) to run it. Should I wrap `nvm.agent` in an agentset and pass that to `nvmContext.runExclusively`? If so, what's the easiest way to wrap an agent in agentset? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method #1**

The quicker-but-arguably-dirtier method is to use `runExclusiveJob`, as demonstrated in (e.g.) the `create-red-turtles` command in https://github.com/NetLogo/Sample-Scala-Extension/blob/master/src/SampleScalaExtension.scala .

To wrap the current agent in an agentset, you can use `agent.AgentSetBuilder`. (You could also pass an `Array[Agent]` of length 1 to one of the `ArrayAgentSet` constructors, but I'd recommend `AgentSetBuilder` since it's less reliant on internal implementation details which are likely to change.)

**Method #2**

The disadvantage of method #1 is the slight constant overhead associated with creating and setting up the extra `AgentSet`, `Job`, and `Context` objects and directing execution through them.

Creating and running a separate job isn't actually how built-in commands like `if` and `while` work. Instead of making a new job, they remain in the current job and cause commands in a command block to run (or not run) by manipulating the instruction pointer (`nvm.Context.ip`) to jump into them or skip over them.

I believe an extension command could do the same. I'm not certain if it has been tried before, but I can't see any reason it wouldn't work.

Doing it this way would involve understanding more about NetLogo engine internals, as documented at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Engine-architecture . You'd model your primitive after e.g. https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/5.0.x/src/main/org/nlogo/prim/etc/_if.java , including altering your implementation of `nvm.CustomAssembled`. (Note that `prim._extern`, which runs extension commands, delegates its `assemble` method to the wrapped command's own `assemble` method, so this should work.) In your `assemble` method, instead of calling `done()` at the end to terminate the job, you'd just allow execution to fall through.

I could try to construct an example that works this way, but it'd take me a couple hours; it's probably not worth me doing unless there's a real need.

Comment: It doesn't look like `agent.AgentSetBuilder` exists anymore. That said, it's easy enough to use the `ArrayAgentSet(Class[? extends Agent], Array[Agent], World)` constructor of `ArrayAgentSet`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, `AgentSetBuilder` is master/headless stuff. In a 5.0.x context, yeah, you're doing the right thing.